# Laravel apiResource() response wrong method

Tags: php, laravel

I have some problem with a route in laravel when I need to use `apiResource()`.
I have this both routes bellow:

```
Route::apiResource('tasks', TasksController::class);
Route::apiResource('tasks/status', TasksStatusController::class);
```

The problem is, when I call GET /api/tasks/status ... the request calling GET /api/tasks with param status. So the request throw an error cause try to response to return the method `show($id)` of the controller `TasksController` with 'status' as parameter. Not the method `index()` of the `TasksStatusController`.

Has anyone seen this type of problem on the Laravel route?

My Laravel version is the: v6.20.44

Comment: Switch the order. It will go down the routes list until it finds the first match, so it's hitting `tasks` first

Comment: Ohh switching the order works fine! Thanks.

Comment: why would you have an entire resource just for a status?  perhaps you mean to make a single end point for status?  .. `Route::get('tasks/status', ...)` and put it before your other definition ... It is directly in the documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/controllers#restful-supplementing-resource-controllers

Comment: The database and archteture isn't defined for me, but the tasks/status is a crud of a domain table. And need all methods POST/GET/PUT and DELETE.

Comment: gotcha, `Route::apiResource('tasks.status', ...)` (nested resource) should do the trick for you ... Good luck and have fun ... https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/controllers#restful-nested-resources

Comment: Very nice @lagbox, thanks, I think this is the good one solution.